# Extracting the name of the file until the first space into a new column

Tags: workflow, flow, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I am trying to create a automated flow which will copy the file name into a new column up until the first space in the name. For example:

The uploaded file name is ****ZKAL12345-I RTR 123ml Product Label Region 61.PDF** so i would like the column to be name **ZKAL12345-I**

I've found the below code, which works well, however, it stops the naming at the dash (-) and as i am sure you can still im not quite sure how to change it to the requirement above .

```
substring(triggerBody()?['{Name}'], 0, lastIndexOf(triggerBody()?['{Name}'],'-'))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks,
Artur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just do

```
substring(triggerBody()?['{Name}'], 0, indexOf(triggerBody()?['{Name}'],' '))
```

?

`indexOf()` returns the *first* index of the searched for value, in this case, a single space, which in your case would be the space between "ZKAL12345-I" and "RTR".

Comment: Haha, Thank you. That worked. For some reason, I didn't remove the "last" when I tried it.